# can't choose MySQL as Data Source in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2015

I want to install MySQL on Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with Windows 10 and use it with the Entity Framework.

---

I followed instructions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-making-a-connection.html), but I can't see "MySQL Database" in the "Change DataSource"-Dialog. 
[image]

There also is no MySQL-Toolbar entry describe [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-mysql-toolbar.html)....

What I have installed so far:

[image]

Has any body an idea how i can get this work?
Thanks in advance!